# How long should we wait before answering our own questions?

Tags: discussion

With respect to this [stackoverflow blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), I again, recently encountered a problem that I have had a better understanding of for some time. It could be useful to post a Question/Answer pair on the main site.

I'd like to know what would be a good amount of time to wait after asking the question, before I submit my answer?

I ask this because, even though I have what I *think* is a good answer, I'm still very interested to see what view the community has.

Comment: I find this whole thing distasteful and disingenuous.  You appear to refuse to accept anybody else's answers to your questions, but just can't wait to accept your own.

Comment: Where have I accepted my own answer that leads you to believe I can't wait to do it? (BTW, not once, ever). Incorrect on both assumptions. Also, what do you find distasteful about freely sharing experiences and information?

Comment: You would not have asked this question on meta if your intent was other than to start asking questions for the purpose of answering them yourself.

Comment: There is a difference between answering your own question and accepting your own answer that seems to have eluded you.

Comment: Time will tell.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel your answer will influence the answers that others post, you may want to wait for a few answers or days before adding your own.  Otherwise, I see no point in waiting.